# How to get the object of parent usecontrol in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, relativesource

I have created a user control lets say UserControl1. I have a child control button, by clicking on which I want to pass the object of the UserControl1 and the data bound with the button to the converter. I am using MVVM pattern for command execution.

Lets say the Xaml file for User Control is structured as below

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Class="UserControl1
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyConverter" 
xmlns:......>
```

somewhere in the Xaml there is a Listbox containing the ListItem and a button for doing some action on the ListBox as represented below

```
 <ListBox x:Name="SomeViewmodel" MinWidth="300" MaxWidth="300" Height ="Auto"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
             <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding someproperty}" Grid.Column="0">
                 </TextBlock>
                 <Border 
                     <Button x:Name="btn1" ">
                         <Image Source="someImage.png"/>
                         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                             <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="Commands:MyCommand" >
                                       <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{Converters:MyConverter}">
                                            <Binding />
                                            <Binding  Source="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}"  />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                             </i:EventTrigger>
                         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     </Button>
                 </Border>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I am able to send the object to the converter but the object recieved at converter is of type **System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource** where as it should be **UserControl1**.

What am I missing? or what should I do to get the UserControl1 Object from RelativeSourceObject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding should be as follows:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{Converters:MyConverter}">
    <Binding />
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}"  />
</MultiBinding>
```

i.e. The binding should use the `RelativeSource` property, not the `Source` property.

Comment: This worked for me. very small change, but took a lot of head banging..

Answer (score 0):

*Updated:*

Try this code:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this... but Name attribute can not be asigned to user control

Comment: @mayurrathi, sorry, i changed the answer. you can test it, i hope it was a shorter solution for you.